# How to send the RACSignal to cell's viewMode when click a button outside of the Cells

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, racsignal

I have a button on navigation bar, that named "Edit". And a `UICollectionView` show with some content. 
To click the "Edit" button will make into a "EditMode", and the button's title become "Done", the `UICollectionView`'s cell should also updated. Click the "Done" button will do the reverse.

I have write the code bellow:
Now after click the "Edit"|"Done" button, the hole collection View will be updated with a refresh, since there's images in the cell get from service which I don't update them. I prefer just update the icon by Cell's signal. but How to refactor the code?

**1.viewController's**   `-(void)viewDidLoad`

```
 [[[[self.editButton rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
    doNext:^(UIButton *sender) {
        if ([sender.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Edit"]) {
            [sender setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }else{
            [sender setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }]
    flattenMap:^RACStream *(UIButton *sender) {
        BOOL isEditMode = [sender.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Edit"];
        return [RACSignal return:@(isEditMode)];
    }] subscribeNext:^(NSNumber* x) {
        [self.viewModel setEditMode:x.boolValue];
    }];

  // Binding to view model
  [[RACObserve(self.viewModel, dataArray) 
     deliverOnMainThread] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
         @strongify(self);
         [self.collectionView reloadData];
     }];
```

**2.1.viewController's ViewModel's** `property`

```
 @property (nonatomic, assign, getter= isEditMode) BOOL editMode;
```

**2.2.viewController's   ViewModel's**  `-(id)init`

```
  self.isEditModeSignal = RACObserve(self, isEditMode);
```

**3.viewController's**  `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

```
  DataModel* item = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  [cellViewModel setDataModel:item
         withIsEditModeSignal:self.viewModel.isEditModeSignal];
  [Cell setCellViewModel:cellViewModel];
```

**4.Cell's ViewModel's** `-(void)setDataModel:(DataModel)data withIsEditModeSignal:(RACSignal*)isEditModeSignal`

```
 self.thing1Signal = [[RACSignal combineLatest:@[self.isEditModeSignal,
                                                     other1Signal,
                                                     other2Signal]
                                 reduce:^id(NSNumber *isEditMode,
                                            NSNumber *other1,
                                            NSNumber *other2){
                                     return @(isEditMode.boolValue && other1.boolValue && other2.boolValue);
                                 }];

 self.thing2Signal = [[RACSignal combineLatest:@[self.isEditModeSignal,
                                                     other3Signal,
                                                     other4Signal]
                                 reduce:^id(NSNumber *isEditMode,
                                            NSNumber *other3,
                                            NSNumber *other4){
                                     return @(isEditMode.boolValue && other3.boolValue && other4.boolValue);
                                 }];
```

**5.Cell.m's** `-(void)setCellViewModel:(CellViewModel*)viewModel`

```
 [[[self.viewModel.thing1Signal deliverOnMainThread] takeUntil:self.rac_prepareForReuseSignal]  subscribeNext:^(NSNumber *isHidden) {
  self.icon1.hidden = isHidden.boolValue;
 }];

 [[[self.viewModel.thing2Signal deliverOnMainThread] takeUntil:self.rac_prepareForReuseSignal]  subscribeNext:^(NSNumber *isHidden) {
  self.icon2.hidden = isHidden.boolValue;
 }];
```

Comment: AS @eckesicle mentioned, I should use if instead of combineLatest here.

Answer (score 0):

Aha,  I found the problem:  I use `self.isEditModeSignal = RACObserve(self, isEditMode);`   Which I should use `self.isEditModeSignal = RACObserve(self, editMode);`.  That's the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

This code is really bad. You're not using ReactiveCocoa the way it is meant to.
A better way is to be binding between cellviewmodels and collectionview viewmodels. No need to trigger a refresh at all.

Like so:

```
// In cell viewmodel's init method:
RAC(self,isEditMode) = RACObserve(self, collectionViewModel.isEditMode); 
//Bind view stuff to: RACObserve(self,isEditMode)

//In collectionview viewmodel init method:
RAC(self,isEditMode) = [[[self.editButton.rac_command executionSignals] flatten] scanWithStart:@NO reduce:id^(NSNumber * running, id next) {
  return @(![running boolValue]);
}];

//In collectionview
RAC(self.editButton.titleLabel, text) = [RACObserve(self.viewModel, isEditMode) map:(NSString *)^(NSNumber * x) {
  [x boolValue] ? @"Edit" : @"Done";
}];
```

And instead of using combineLatest use the if signal.

Comment: yes, I don't need to observe editButton's button click event to reload the data.

Comment: Hi, why do you need  flatten here?

Comment: If I not misunderstood, your code for isEditMode will only be YES when button is clicked down and before things finished. Actually for my requirement, click the button just switch into edit mode and that's it. and edit will happen later.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22366964.  `executionSignals] flatten] scanWithStart ` will not fire.